# PHPVIBE - video doesn't create the thumbnail

Tags: ffmpeg, phpvibe

I have installed phpvibe4 on my surver my website name is surfoye.com I have enabled FFMPEG settings in the admin area, but still it doesn't create any video thumbnail and time duration after uploading any video from my computer.

if someone has experienced this please assist me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Install ffmpeg you can fix it or get a webhosting company which contains ffmpeg I recommend c-server.jp/en

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have ffmpeg installed? 
Are the paths edited well to your server's ffmpeg in phpvibe's admin? 
Have you searched this in their forum, they have tens of topics.
You can also use the tester under their "Requirements".